# Calendar: Receiving Google calendar invites as email, not in iOS calendar app

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, gmail, ical

My girlfriend has a Gmail set up on her iPhone, attached to her AppleID of the same email address. Her Google Calendar is synced with iOS Calendar and works a treat.

The issue is, when she sends me an invite via her calendar to my AppleID, I receive it as an email from Gmail, not as a new event in my calendar.

When I send her an invite, it arrives in her iOS calendar and can be added with ease.

How do I fix this so I’m receiving Google Calendar invites into the Calendar app on iOS, not as an email from Gmail?